# Why does lighting on figure look bad at certain locations?

Tags: faces, lighting, smooth, matcaps

I'm trying to figure out why I can see some polygons when I put a MatCap on my figure, but I can't see others (figure looks very smooth there). It isn't because of the size of the polygons I don't think, as they are around the same size. Anyways, if I subdivide the polygons that stand out they still stand out. What is the reason for this?

[image]

whereas this is what I see in the UV Editor:

[image: #fac]

Comment: I think we'll need to see your Blend file. You can share it via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page and then edit your question here and paste the link into it. That second image isn't the UV editor screen. It looks more like Edit mode in the 3D view.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Solution is to add smoothing to object. I'm not super smart in blender, but as I'm finding solutions elsewhere I'm realizing these are fundamental options that nobody on stackexchange seems to know...